# Kotlin convert Map<Key, Value> to Map<key, List<Value>>

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way to create Map of ?
Below I'm showing what I got for now. First solution is much cleaner but requires to get another object what I don't need (functional programming).

```
    val result: MutableMap<key, MutableList<Int>> = mutableMapOf()

    someArray.onEach { (key, int) ->
        result
            .computeIfAbsent(key.id) { mutableListOf() }
            .add(int)
    }

    return list
```

I got something like this which is not so clean

```
    return someArray
        .map { (key, int) ->
            key.id to int
        }
        .groupBy { it.first }
        .map { (k, v) ->
            k to v.filter { it.first == k }
                .map { it.second }
        }
```

Comment: wait... your second one does not really give the same result as the first, right?

Comment: your title is misleading... at least it does not look like that you transform a `Map<Key, Value>` to `Map<Key, List<Value>>` but rather it looks like you want to create a `Map<Key, List<Value>>` from something like `Sequence<Pair<Key, Value>>`.... could you please confirm or deny and update the question accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) supports a second parameter which can be used to immediately transform the values, so you only need the following (note: also integrated the `map`-call into the key selector):

```
someArray.groupBy({ it.first.id }, { it.second })
```